# ASP.NET FileUpload Cannot access a closed file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm aware there are several other questions like this on SO, however every answer I've tried so far from a range of websites, SO, MSDN etc etc, have all proven to have no impact on the error.

I've got an `asp:FileUpload` which, on change, I'm storing in a session variable (I have other fields which cause post back's so need to ensure that I've got the file the user's uploaded somewhere).

The error I am getting is

```
{"Cannot access a closed file."}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146232798
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: "Cannot access a closed file."
ObjectName: ""
Source: "mscorlib"
StackTrace: "   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent.TempFile.GetBytes(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Byte[] buffer, Int32 bufferOffset)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent.CopyBytes(Int32 offset, Byte[] buffer, Int32 bufferOffset, Int32 length)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   at GCSearchPortal.GlobalFunctions.UploadFile[T](HttpServerUtility server, FileType type, T file, Int32 id) in C:\\Users\\zach.ross-clyne\\Source\\Workspaces\\GC Search Portal\\GCSearchPortal\\GCSearchPortal\\GlobalFunctions.cs:line 241"
TargetSite: {Void FileNotOpen()}
```

This is what's in my web.config in the `system.web` section

```
<httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="1048576" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1073741824"/>
```

The code that is causing the issue is this:

```
internal static int UploadFile<T>(HttpServerUtility server, FileType type, T file, int id)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(HtmlInputFile) || typeof(T) == typeof(FileUpload))
    {
        string fileName = null;
        string location = null;

        dynamic fileUpload = file;

        if (fileUpload.PostedFile != null && fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Get a reference to PostedFile object */
                HttpPostedFile attFile = fileUpload.PostedFile;

                /* Get size of the file */
                int attachFileLength = attFile.ContentLength;
                /* Make sure the size of the file is > 0  */
                if (attachFileLength > 0)
                {
                    if (attachFileLength < 52428800)
                    {
                        /* Get extension for file */
                        string ext = Path.GetExtension(attFile.FileName);

                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case FileType.TermsOfBusiness:
                                location = "~/Clients/" + id + "/";
                                fileName = "TOB";
                                break;
                            case FileType.TermsOfRole:
                                location = "~/Jobs/" + id + "/";
                                fileName = "TOR";
                                break;
                            case FileType.CandidateCV:
                                location = "~/Candidates/" + id + "/";
                                fileName = "CV";
                                break;
                            case FileType.NewCV:
                                location = "~/CVs/";
                                fileName = id.ToString();
                                break;
                        }

                        fileName += ext;

                        /* Save the file on the server */
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(server.MapPath(location));

                        string filePath = attFile.FileName;
                        string fileName2 = fileUpload.FileName;
                        Stream fStream = fileUpload.FileContent;
                        byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];

                        fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length); // <<<<< This line causes the crash

                        File.WriteAllBytes(server.MapPath(location + fileName), contents);

                        // This is what the code was at the very beginning before all my changes
                        //attFile.SaveAs(server.MapPath(location + fileName));

                        return 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 3;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 1; // <<<<< This is where it's crashing and giving the error above
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Passed type is not supported");
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: What line actually throws the exception? Not the actual catch statement, but the line that causes the catch.

Comment: `fStream.Read` and the commented out `attFile.SaveAs` when that's being used (which was the initial code)

Comment: change useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl to false, <system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="20000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
</system.web>

Comment: Just given that a go, still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int fileLength = attFile.ContentLength;

byte[] byteContent = new byte[fileLength];
attFile.InputStream.Read(byteContent, 0, iLength);
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(byteContent))
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(server.MapPath(location + fileName), memStream .ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Still has exactly the same issue. The line it crashes on is `attFile.InputStream.CopyTo`.

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne Have you examined the InputStream property does it have any content?

Comment: It has a length of 433994 so I imagine that it does?

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne see my edit try that and see if it works any better

Comment: I've already tried using `InputStream.Read` to no avail. Sorry its being a nightmare

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne just try the exact code above, it's not using the Stream for sizing the byte array which is subtly different than your original code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128922/discussion-between-csl-and-zach-ross-clyne).